# Pylint load-plugins fails in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint

Here is my config:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins", 
    "pylint-quotes"
  ],
```

I installed pylint-quotes with pip and pip3 but I still get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pylint", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 16, in run_pylint
    Run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1274, in __init__
    linter.load_plugin_modules(self._plugins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 500, in load_plugin_modules
    module = modutils.load_module_from_name(modname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astroid/modutils.py", line 190, in load_module_from_name
    return load_module_from_modpath(dotted_name.split('.'), path, use_sys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astroid/modutils.py", line 232, in load_module_from_modpath
    mp_file, mp_filename, mp_desc = imp.find_module(part, path)
ImportError: No module named pylint-quotes
```

I'm using mac. Should I specify somewhere a path to modules?

Comment: you should check if pylint-quotes is installed, cause I have the same problem with ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]. After installing pylint_django package the problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin name is **pylint_quotes**.

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
"--load-plugins", 
"pylint_quotes"
],
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the same python at both places? It might be the case that you are installing with different python (pip) and using another in VS.

Comment: what does pip -V returns you? Is this version same as you are using in pyhton try the below code inside py file using VS ------- 

`(CODE LINE 1) import sys 

(CODE LINE 2)print(sys.executable)`

Comment: pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: See you are using 3.7 in VS and installed the package in 2.7 using pip...use pip 3 to install the package.

Comment: Installed for python 3 too. It's still not working. The weird thing is that:
`mac-1icxlocal:test mac-1$ pip install pylint_quotes
Requirement already satisfied: pylint_quotes in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.1.8)`
But in the same time it's not there. I'm trying to run it manually as you can see but it's still not working. `pylint test.py --load-plugins pylint-quotes`